is it possible to load cluster using advanced marker in google maps JS api?
I’m working on a Angular project where I need to implement clustering using Google Maps with AdvancedMarkerElement. The function which i shared as text file is works as expected when using standard markers, but I'm running into some issues with clustering when switching to AdvancedMarkerElement.
Has anyone else experienced similar issues when working with AdvancedMarkerElement in clusters? What’s the best way to approach clustering when using AdvancedMarkerElement?
Any help or guidance on this would be very helpful. Thank you!
async loadGeoJsonPointsAsCluster(pointFeatures: any[],fileName?:any) {
  let iconType = ''
  if(fileName == ".txt"){
    iconType = "xxx"
  }else if(fileName == ".txt"){
     iconType = "yyy"
  }else if(fileName == "rgDeviceType.txt"){
     iconType = "zzz"
  }
  const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");

const squareSymbol = {
  path: 'M -1 -1 L 1 -1 L 1 1 L -1 1 Z',
  scale: 10, 
  fillColor: 'orange',
  fillOpacity: 1,
  strokeColor: 'white', 
  strokeWeight: 2
};
const circleSymbol = {
  path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
  scale: 7, 
  fillColor: 'green', 
  fillOpacity: 1, 
  strokeColor: 'white', 
  strokeWeight: 2
};

const that = this
const icon:any = {
  path: 'M 0 -6 L -6 0 L 0 6 L 6 0 Z', 
  scale: 1,
  fillColor: 'blue',
  fillOpacity: 1,
  strokeWeight: 1,
  strokeColor: 'White'
}
  const markers = pointFeatures.map((feature: any) => {
    const coords = feature.geometry.coordinates;

    var marker = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
            position: { lat: coords[1], lng: coords[0] },
      icon: iconType == "zzz"? icon :  iconType == "yyy"? circleSymbol : squareSymbol  ,
      zIndex:  iconType == "zzz"?  10000  : 0
    });

    const infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -30)
    });

    marker.addListener('mouseover', () => {
      let contentString = '';

     
      const properties = feature.properties;
      for (const key in properties) {
        if (properties.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          contentString += `<strong>${key}</strong>: ${properties[key]}<br>`;
        }
      }

      if (contentString) {
        infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
        infoWindow.setPosition(marker.getPosition());
        infoWindow.open(this.map);
      }
    });

    marker.addListener('mouseout', () => {
      infoWindow.close();
    });

    return marker;
  });
  const clusterCalculator = (type:any) => {

    return function (markers: any[], numStyles: number){
    const count = markers.length;
  
    const size = Math.min(40 + count * 2, 100);  
  
    return {
      text: count.toString(),
      index: 0,  
      size: size,  
      url: 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(createSvgIcon(size, count,type).trim()),  
       zIndex: type === 'zzz' ? 10000 : type === 'xxx' ? 5000 : 0, 
    };
  }
  };
  const createSvgIcon = (size: number, count: number,type:any): string => {
    
    if(iconType == "zzz"){
    return `
      <svg width="${size}" height="${size}" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <g clip-path="url(#clipDiamond)">
          <path d="M10 2 L18 10 L10 18 L2 10 Z" fill="#0d80f2" stroke="white"/>
          <text x="10" y="11" text-anchor="middle" fill="white" dy=".3em" font-size="${Math.max(7, size / 3)}"></text>
        </g>
      </svg>
    `;
    }else if(iconType =="xxx"){
      return ` <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="${size}" height="${size}" viewBox="0 0 35 35">
                        <circle cx="17.5" cy="17.5" r="17" fill="green" />
                        <text x="20" y="20" text-anchor="middle" fill="white" dy=".3em" font-weight="700" font-size="12"></text>
                    </svg>`
    }else{
      return `<svg width="${size}" height="${size}" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect width="30" height="30" style="fill:orange;stroke:white;"/>
</svg>`
    }
  };
this.clusterMarkers = markers;
  this.markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(this.map, markers, {
  gridSize : 60,
  calculator: clusterCalculator(iconType),
  imagePath: '',  
  maxZoom:14,
  
});




  this.layers[fileName] = this.markerCluster; 

}

i tried to load without marker but its not compailing

Related questions: How to cluster Advanced Marker Element (google map) using Marker Clusterer?, Google Maps API v3 Algorithm (MarkerClusterer) not working
